# Integrating Apache PDFBox to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, pdfbox

Any idea how can I integrate the apache pdfbox method to my jsp?

I'm trying to create a hyperlink or a button in jsp to call the java I created.

I saw a lot of recommendations about creating a servlet but I'm not very familiar with how it works and wanted a simpler one.

.JSP

```
<td>
<form ACTION=".java" METHOD="POST">
<input type="submit"  value="Download"/>
</form>
</td>
```

.JAVA

```
public class TestPDF {

public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {

PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
PDPage newPage = new PDPage();
document.addPage( newPage );
document.save(new File("C:/Users/test.pdf"));
document.close();
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Let us know your full requirements. I worked with PDFBox. Hope I can help you.

Comment: I created a java from what is shown above, and I need to call that java to generate the pdf using my jsp file

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have three steps for this:
1. handle the upload file in the jsp file [JSP - File Uploading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_file_uploading.htm)
2. then @ page import the apache pdfbox class in the jsp
3. do the convert in the jsp body  in <% %>, and render the result